# JMeter APDEX report as raw CSV

Tags: jmeter

I love the APDEX report and I would like to perform some aggregations with the raw statistics results from various runs.

This is the [oficial page documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) and I'm interested in the table described as

> A Statistics table providing in one table a summary of all metrics per transaction including 3 configurable percentiles

**Is there any way to get this data as a raw CSV for post processing?**

I'm only able to find this processed data inside the output as JS format. And I'm not aware of any listener generating the same kind of results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more RTFM I found that

- Jmeter listeners do not store results when executed from command line
- jtl file can be post processed to generate other reports

with that there is a plugin called [jpgc-synthesis](https://jmeter-plugins.org/?search=jpgc-synthesis) that can do that.

Install it and after the test is run launch it from cmd with something like

`C:\jmeter\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin\PluginsManagerCMD.bat  --tool Reporter --generate-csv c:\jmeter\aggregateResults.csv --input-jtl c:\jmeter\results.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport`

It has all the requests grouped with those columns in a friendly CSV for post processing

`sampler_label,aggregate_report_count,average,aggregate_report_median,aggregate_report_90%_line,aggregate_report_95%_line,aggregate_report_99%_line,aggregate_report_min,aggregate_report_max,aggregate_report_error%,aggregate_report_rate,aggregate_report_bandwidth,aggregate_report_stddev`

Comment: BTW I installed the plugins because of what I read here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jmeter-plugins/Da4YN_nLvJA

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Command-Line Graph Plotting Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) in order to be able to generate various reports and charts out of JMeter .jtl results files

The plugin can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Plugins Command Line Graph Plotting Tool]

Upon successful installation you will see `JMeterPluginsCMD.bat` and `JMeterPluginsCMD.sh` scripts under JMeter "bin" folder and you will be able to produce something similar to APDEX report with command-line like:

```
JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-csv test.csv --input-jtl test.jtl --plugin-type SynthesisReport
```